How to strip off Timezone part from DateTime to leave only local DateTime part? (no string parsing or manipulations)
I have a similar question to this one: How to strip timezone from DateTime in .NET Core, but I don't want to use any string based parsings.
Basically I have events coming from various locations in the world with their timestamps collected with DateTime.Now
I want to report Events with their corresponding local creation timestamps (not utc).
So given that each datetime is basically represented like this:
2024-05-08T17:31:53.9744487+03:00
I want to extract just 2024-05-08T17:31:53.9744487 as a DateTime, so that I could report local time of the Event.
I don't want to do any string parsing as in the answer above (or any string manipulations) as those are prone to errors.
Here is a test case I would like to pass:
[Fact]
public void DateTimeConversionTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var testDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2024-05-08T17:31:53.9744487+03:00");
    var expectedTimeString = "17:31:53";

    // Act
    var convertedDateTime = testDateTime; // convert DateTime to local DateTime here
    var convertedTimeString = convertedDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expectedTimeString, convertedTimeString);
}

This seems to be a surprisingly difficult problem to solve in C# as I couldn't find anything working online.
Anybody knows how to solve it?
EDIT: After explanation by Derrick and Guru below, I realise this question is not correct, as the date parsed from the string loses its Timezone offset right away. So the solution would be to use DateTimeOffset instead
EDIT2: For anyone else struggling with the same System.Text.Json deserialization receiving DateTime as a string such as 2024-05-08T17:31:53.9744487+03:00 and trying to strip timezone, the solution turned out to be just to change the type of the receiving object's property from DateTime to DateTimeOffset.
Then System.Text.Json deserializes it correctly to DateTimeOffset and then DateTimeOffset manipulation becomes possible, like getting DateTimeOffset.DateTime, which solves the issue of stripping timezone.
So assumming this class:
public class MyEvent
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedUtc { get; set; }
}

is changed to this:
public class MyEvent
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedUtc { get; set; }
}

this now works correctly:
var myEvent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyEvent>(json)
and we can use myEvent.Created.DateTime to get DateTime without Timezone.

"so that I could report local time of the Event." - and what is the local offset? Can you please elaborate the problem a bit more? What output are you getting?

Do you have the offset? If so, create a new DateTimeOffset object with your date object and the offset as as TimeSpan object.

I don't have the offset, but all the information required is already provided within DateTime. I mean you can visually see the local date time when looking at it.

That's local date time where your server is located. You'll either need the time zone or the offset.

DateTime.Parse() is returning a local datetime, the timezone is already lost at that point and you can't put it back unless it's always +03:00 and you want to hardcode it?

Which property of DateTime has the original local time? testDateTime should be in the local time of the server / application that is running the code.

If I understand you correctly - you can use DateTimeOffset with DateTimeOffset.DateTime property:

The DateTime property is not affected by the value of the Offset property.

var parsed = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2024-05-08T17:31:53.9744487+01:00");
var originalLocalDateTime = parsed.DateTime; // DateTimeKind.Unspecified


Given the test case I wrote above, how would you manipulate testDateTime to do this?

@Tanuki var testDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(..) and then using it - var convertedTimeString = testDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); does the trick for me.

I mean, if you have datetime variable created like this already: var testDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2024-05-08T17:31:53.9744487+03:00"); how would you do it without string parsing or manipulation?

@Tanuki - you don't. That's it. DateTime does not store information about the original timezone/offset, so unless you can get that info from the original string (or in some other way) you can't do much here. Basically you are working with the wrong abstraction here.

I doesn't make sense to me. When looking at string representation you can see +03:00, which is exactly what should be used. Why can this not be used somehow?

@Tanuki what string representation are you talking about exactly? The one which is send to the DateTime.Parse? If yes - it is used to convert the time to the local timezone (basically timezone of the server you are running on). But this offset is not preserved by the type.

+03:00 is UTC offset, so it should be possible to get correct local datetime by stripping this 03:00 hours. No separate offset should be necessary

After calling DateTime.Parse() your newly returned DateTime object doesn't contain the original offset. You can't put it back if all you have is testDateTime.

@Tanuki  again, when you will parse the datetime it will process that +03:00 offset and will use it to convert the datetime string to local time (server) with it's offset, if your local timezone offset matches the one in the string then the time you have at hands is already a local time.

@Tanuki i.e. my current TZ offset is +03:00 so your test will just pass for me. But if the string would have different offset (for example +01:00) or my offset would be different then it will not, and it is impossible to get the +01:00 from the parsed DateTime itself.

I understand now, thank you both Derrick and Guru for explaining. My question is wrong with the DateTime.Parse() example. In reality my data comes as a Json string and the time offset is lost during string to object conversion. Now I understand why. Let me see if it is possible to modify question better (or just accept that I asked the impossible)

@Tanuki sounds like you can just use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime in your object and that's it.

Yes, this seems like a solution indeed. I will need to find how to do that for the STJ JsonSerializer.Deserialize, but thats a different question/research altogether.
Thank you for the help.
